# How to get the ZFTool working?

Tags: zend-framework2, zftool2

The ZFTool isn't working (anymore) on my Debian VM.

```
$ which zf
/usr/local/bin/zf
$ ls -lia /usr/local/bin/ | grep "zf"
... zf -> /usr/share/.composer/vendor/bin/zf.php
$ cd /usr/share/.composer
$ composer info | grep "zftool"
zendframework/zftool  v0.1.0  Utility module for Zend Framework 2 applications.
$ echo $COMPOSER_HOME
/usr/share/.composer
```

Now when I start it:

```
$ zf create module Foo
OR
$ $COMPOSER_HOME/vendor/bin/zf.php create module Foo
OR
$ php $COMPOSER_HOME/vendor/bin/zf.php create module Foo
```

I get this error:

> Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided

So I cannot run the ZFTool jobs like `config`, `classmap generate` etc.

**What is the issues caused by and how to get the ZFTool working?**

Comment: Have you added the zftool to module.config.php

Comment: To add the ZFTool to the `module.config.php`?.. No, I haven't. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean where every you are enabling the modules in the config 'Modules' => [ .. ] but I guess you are if you get the strapline back

Answer (score 0):

You're simply providing incorrect arguments as it says. That error is coming from withing ZF2 so you're triggering it, but there's There's no -h option.

try

```
./vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php
```

or

```
./vendor/bin/zf.php
```

no arguments and from within your root directory, you'll get a list of options.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your are right, there is no parameter `-h`. I've just edited the question and replaced the `-h` by `create module Foo`. But the issue is remaining the same.

Comment: Just installed ZFTool locally and tried it out, as you suggested. Both attempts (`./vendor/zendframework/zftool/zf.php create module Foo` and `./vendor/bin/zf.php create module Foo`) failed: `Reason for failure: Invalid arguments or no arguments provided`.

Comment: if you pass no parameters do you get a list of options?

Comment: Yes, I get it (and the `Reason for failure ...` under it) always -- with and also without parameters.

Comment: seems like an issue with the cli roots, have you written any code that overrides the default zftool routes maybe?

Comment: Hm... Actually not. I didn't define any CLI routes in this project.